# Unknown property ‘-moz-binding’. Declaration dropped

Tags: css, firefox, xss

`-moz-binding` was always a security threat to websites. To the point were mozilla considered dropping it.

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=324253

Nonetheless, it survived. But now firefox fires a warning `Unknown property ‘-moz-binding’.  Declaration dropped.` whenever editing an html tag `style` attribute from browser-console.

Is `-moz-binding` still supported ?

Comment: [MDN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WWQnh.png)

Comment: @SagarV sorry I forgot to mention I'm using firefox developer edition

Comment: That doesn't make a different. It may contain experimental features. Since it is specifically made for developers, I don't think they'll support deprecated properties which are still being supported by normal firefox.